# AJAX MySQL Query Orderby

Tags: mysql

I need to return a database table in a .php script (the AJAX file). I currently have this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$gettblstmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT *
                             FROM `tbl1` 
                             ORDER BY `ordernum`');
$gettblstmt->execute();
$tbl= $gettblstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($tbl);
```

Now, I'm using the `$.post` function from `jQuery` to 'run' the PHP script. However, since the result of the AJAX file is an object, the `ORDER BY` won't be applied.

How could I get the right ordering from MySQL into jQuery?

```
$.post('someajaxfile.php', function(result) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
    {
        $('#someelement').append(result[i] + '<br>');
    }
});
```

Comment: where is javascript code?

Comment: Please complete the snippets from client to server since you have mentioned AJAX

Comment: json_encode does not changes the ordering. If the results come from mysql ordered (which seems to be the case) then this ordering will be kept inside the json object as well

Comment: I forgot the JS... my apologize, it's pretty early and I'm not fully awake.

Comment: @ElzoValugi the point is in my DIV the right order isn't applied. For example, item b which has order 1 will be placed after item a which has order 2.

Comment: check if the php result is ordered by using console.log(result). and then use $.each to properly add elements from your result set to a #someelement

Answer (score 0):

The "Order" of data from the PDO query is actually preserved when it is thrown back to the client. When the data is encoded to JSON, the objects or items are still ordered according to the array order retrieved from the query.

What you can do to alter the ordering?

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$gettblstmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT *
                             FROM `tbl1` 
                             ORDER BY `ordernum`');
$gettblstmt->execute();
$tbl= $gettblstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($tbl);
```

First, the `ORDER BY ordernum` can accept `ORDER BY ordernum DESC` or `ORDER BY ordernum ASC` depending on your requirements.

Second, in the client's code or your jQuery code. You can change the method of how you add the items.

From appending:

```
$('#someelement').append(result[i] + '<br>');
```

You can change to prepending:

```
$('#someelement').prepend(result[i] + '<br>');
```

Note:  In your example code, you are appending the whole object and not the indiviual item from your JSON. You are not using the `i` variable inside the append. So in your current code, you might see `[object Object]`.

Comment: I made a mistake - it's still early and I'm kind of sleepy - so I forgot the `[1]`. But I don't get what you mean: seeing from what you've posted, it's the same as I have right now,